# Margin: Auto not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, margin, text-align

URL: http://cyberbat.co.uk/test container margin: auto is not working, is there any other way to put it in the middle in IE.

EDIT: Check it again, the index.php was the wrong file, I replaced it with index.html .

Comment: Poor question. Show some HTML source, we don't want to have to go find it from your link... and put what in the middle exactly?

Comment: You just need a container for `.page` that its `text-align` should be `center`. IE can't centralize a *block-tag* (like `div`s or `ul`s) via `margin`. See the code below in answer

Comment: Link not working anymore.

Answer (score 24):

This is a bug in IE!
You just need to create a holder for `<div class="page">` and set its `text-align` to `center`

```css
.page-holder{
    text-align:center;
}
.page{
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-holder">
    <div class="page">
    page content
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

Use this on parent container for stupid browsers:

```
text-align: center
```

Answer (score 9):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Your problem is define your file type and standards. if you add to this code to top of your file it will work!

Comment: I added HTML 5's `<!DOCTYPE html>`, now IE behaves as expected. 10x

Answer (score 8):

try using the following on the parent item.

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

Comment: Or display: flex on the parent and align-self: center on the child if you only want that one element vertically centered

Answer (score 3):

You have RAW php code because you didn't configure the server properly:

```
<?php
include('inc/settings.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Resolve that issue by applying PHP to *.html files and `<?php include ?>` won't show up literally. If I recall correctly, adjust this line in the .ini file to be:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm .php
```

Because this literal backend code is in front of the DOCTYPE, it causes quirks mode in IE and in quirks horizontal auto margins don't work properly.

You can go with the text-align:center on parent element, but that's a hack for IE and you should solve this properly by making IE render it in standards mode from my suggestion above.

Answer (score 3):

For  IE, replace my-auto with align-self-center and BINGO. You can also write CSS for the same:

```
.center-container{
   align-self: center;
}
```

Comment: `align-self` is a flexbox property and will not work unless in a flexbox container.

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer displays your website in quirks mode because of this bogus processing instruction at the top of markup:

```
<?php
include('inc/settings.php');
?>
```

Remove it; `margin: auto` works in IE6+. There's **no** need to do `text-align: center` or other unnecessary changes.

Comment: Sorry, that was the php file. Check it again, I put the index.html file to replace the index.php file.

Comment: @Lewes If I open the link you provided, I can still see `<?php ...` at the top of source (press Ctrl+U in your browser to display source).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `meta` record to `head`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

Comment: This actually worked better than all other mentioned methods for getting my page to display in IE11 the same way it does in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can download normalize.css (just google it) and link it to your project, now you can use smth like:

**HTML:**

```
    <main class="container></main>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .container {
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 600px;
```